# Average marginal effects using the linear probability model

Tags: regression, probit, marginal-effect, linear-probability-model

I read that when calculating average marginal effects using the linear probability model, you should always use heteroscedasticity robust standard errors. Why is that?

Comment: Elsewhere on this site you’ll see discussions of the inappropriateness of the linear “probability” model.  Because of the constraints on [0,1] needing to be applied to this model, this induces a lot of boring interactions among the predictors.  I say boring in the sense of being purely statistical and not interpretable from the standpoint of the subject matter.